# Reading a Large File with PowerShell and delete carriage returns

Tags: powershell

I have a large CSV file that I need to scrub off Carriage Returns. The file is an 11 gig dump of a database that I am running through another program. The program chokes on Carriage returns so I am trying to do this:

```
$Readcount = 1000
$CSVFile = <path>    
(Get-Content -Path $CSVFile -Raw -ReadCount $ReadCount) -replace "`r", "" | Set-Content -Path $CSVFile -Force
```

I wanted to stick with GC for it's speed over Import-CSV but when reading this file I get the error:

> Get-Content : Insufficient memory to continue the execution of the program

My max Shell memory is set to unlimited through a GPO.

Comment: when you wrap the G-C call in `()` it forces the whole thing to run BEFORE anything is passed on. make a proper pipeline of it instead by removing the parens and adding a `ForEach-Object` to do the replacement. ///// you may also want to look into using the `-File` option of the `switch` statement since that is apparently quite amazingly fast.

Comment: Thank you, can you provide a link to a greater description of -File? I will try looking at that and get back to you. I had tried the foreach loop but that took way too long.

Comment: from `Get-Help about_Switch` ... `-File = Takes input from a file rather than a value statement. If multiple File parameters are included, only the last one is used. Each line of the file is read and evaluated by the Switch statement.`

Comment: As an aside: `-Raw` (read whole file as a single string) contradicts `-ReadCount` (read lines in batches), and `-ReadCount` is effectively ignored if both parameters are specified. In fact, `Get-Content` should not even _allow_ specifying both: see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11266).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get-Content inside the parentheses will make the whole thing finish first, loading the whole file into memory.  You can do it this way, but you'll have to write to a second file.  Get-Content normally returns no line endings, so a newline is added, and then Set-Content with the -nonewline option is called to not add more line endings.  '$' in regex means 'end of line'.  The readcount option is definitely faster.  Luckily, -replace will work with a 1000 element array.

```
$Readcount = 1000
$CSVFile = 'file.csv'  
$CSVFile2 = 'file2.csv'
Get-Content -Path $CSVFile -ReadCount $Readcount | Foreach { $_ -replace '$',"`n" } | 
  Set-Content -NoNewline $CSVFile2
```

Comment: This definitely works well. Just wish there was a less cumbersome way of accomplishing the goal. Thanks for the assist!

Answer (score 1):

The (probably) fastest way of reading a file line-by-line is by using `switch -File`.
Each line inside the switch will have its newline stripped off.
To append the UNIX **`n** newline character and write out each line without adding an extra line-break, you can use the .NET [AppendAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
$CsvFileIn  = 'X:\file.csv'  
$CsvFileOut = 'X:\file2.csv'  # you cannot overwrite the same file while reading it..

switch -File $CsvFileIn {
    # this will create the file in UTF-8 encoding without BOM
    # If you don't want that, add a third parameter [System.Text.Encoding]::Default
    default { [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($CsvFileOut, "$_`n") }
}
```

Comment: Your variables don't match.

Comment: It's nice to see different methods, but this seems slow compared to set-content.  I can do a million lines in about 19 seconds.

Comment: This also works but does seem to be slightly slower over the course of about 30 million rows which surprised me. In smaller sets I think this is a cleaner option. Up voted it.

Comment: You could wrap the `switch` statement in `& { ... }` and pipe it to `Set-Content`, which would make the solution about as fast as the one in @js2010's answer. The overhead in your current approach comes from opening and closing the output file in every iteration. If you created a stream writer ahead of time and wrote to the open stream in each iteration (shown in my answer), you'd get a substantially faster solution.

Comment: @js2010 The question wasn't about speed,but rather about handling without running out of memory

Answer (score 0):

**The key to speeding up PowerShell solutions is to avoid cmdlets and the pipeline**.

The following combination is significantly faster than the [`Get-Content -ReadCount`-based pipeline solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59165865/45375):

- Use `switch -File` to efficiently loop over the input file's lines.
- Use a [`StreamWriter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter) instance (via [`System.IO.File.CreateText()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.createtext#System_IO_File_CreateText_System_String_)) to write to the output file. (If line-by-line processing is needed to keep memory use down, you cannot write back to the same file in a single operation).

```
# Create a stream writer for the output file, 
# which is created as a BOM-less UTF-8 file by default.
# NOTE: Be sure to use a *full path*, because .NET's current dir. differs from
#       PowerShell's.
$streamWriter = [IO.File]::CreateText("$pwd/Modified.csv")

# Loop over all input lines, which strips the trailing newline,
# append `n (LF), and write as-is to the output file.
switch -file $CSVFile  {
   default { $streamWriter.Write($_ + "`n") }
}

# Close the stream writer.
$streamWriter.Close()
```